# R:eval() ignores scales='free' after parse()

Tags: r, parsing, eval, facet

i have the following

> > `fun<-function(...,facet_string){
> >     code...
> >     aes_facet <-eval(parse(text = paste("facet_grid(",facet.string,")"))) code...
> >     if(facet.string!='') {
> >         p<-p+facet_grid(aes_facet)}`

the output from eval is `facet_grid( ~ col)` 
whereas should be `facet_grid( .~ col), scales='free'`
when i specify `facet_string='.~col,scales=\'free\'`
and then when i want to plot facet_grid the scales are ignored! What i should do to have the expression as it should be with `scales='free'` in?

Comment: Don't use `eval(parse())`. You can pass the faceting formula as a string, which is documented.

Comment: @joran I missed that myself the other day and used `as.formula` when it was unnecessary.  Thanks for the point out: http://docs.ggplot2.org/current/facet_grid.html